# Is there any hook or way to modify the list of countries and states in the Location module?

Tags: location

I'm trying to change the Location module so instead of United Kingdom and its respectives counties, I could have England, North Ireland, Scotland and Wales, with their respectives counties. Do you know way to achieve this via any hook? Any ideas?.

So the idea is to be able to delete a country, and add some country with provinces/states, so they are available in forms and in exposed filters for views, for example.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Location module seems to provide the API. Did you look into http://drupalcode.org/project/location.git/blob/HEAD:/location_API.txt?

Comment: Yes thank you, but none of those functions can give the functionality I need.